# Difference of Dockerized Redis performance between server and local system

Tags: docker, redis, benchmarking, latency

I conduct stress test on my server the result of latency time for **1000 request per second was 1 second**, i found out the latency problem is because of redis so I check dockerized redis performance(benchmark) on CentOS 7 (CentOs is on vmware virtual machine **cpu: 22 core, RAM: 30 GB**) by

```
redis-benchmark -q -n 100000
```

Give me following results:

```
PING_INLINE: 26420.08 requests per second
PING_BULK: 27389.76 requests per second
SET: 27144.41 requests per second
GET: 26702.27 requests per second
INCR: 27041.64 requests per second
LPUSH: 27203.48 requests per second
RPUSH: 27188.69 requests per second
LPOP: 27005.13 requests per second
RPOP: 27367.27 requests per second
SADD: 26645.35 requests per second
HSET: 26881.72 requests per second
SPOP: 27624.31 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 27100.27 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 20703.93 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 11763.32 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 9627.42 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 8078.20 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 26709.40 requests per second
```

But when I’m checking dockerized redis performance(benchmark) on my laptop which is ubuntu 19.04 (**cpu: core i3, RAM: 12GB**) by

```
redis-benchmark -q -n 100000
```

Give me the following results:

```
PING_INLINE: 117096.02 requests per second
PING_BULK: 126742.72 requests per second
SET: 119904.08 requests per second
GET: 126903.55 requests per second
INCR: 127064.80 requests per second
LPUSH: 111482.72 requests per second
RPUSH: 121359.23 requests per second
LPOP: 112994.35 requests per second
RPOP: 123152.71 requests per second
SADD: 130378.09 requests per second
HSET: 130039.02 requests per second
SPOP: 103199.18 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 88809.95 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 51046.45 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 17853.96 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 12784.45 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 9744.69 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 132802.12 requests per second
```

**Why is the performance result of my local system is much better than server despite the server's higher hardware capabilities?**

Comment: you are reaching a server which is allocated on your same machine...(almost) no network latency there.

Comment: I connect to server by ssh and within docker container in server, I've done benchmark

Comment: What exact CPU model do you have in your laptop?  Note that Intel client CPUs have [lower memory latency than big Xeons](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39260020/why-is-skylake-so-much-better-than-broadwell-e-for-single-threaded-memory-throug).  But also, what network connection does your laptop have to the server?  Is it going over gigabit ethernet directly with one hop to a local server, or is it tunneling through SSH over WiFi and a cable-modem + Internet?  If the latter, you're spending CPU time on encrypting / decrypting the traffic!